# Why php's soapCall gives string conversion error?

Tags: php, soap-client

```
 // Set username and password
    $ih_soap_user= $this->config->item('interUser');
    $ih_soap_pass=$this->config->item('interPass');


    //echo $ih_soap_user.':P:'.$ih_soap_pass;
    // Set soap namespace
    $ih_soap_ns = 'http://www.interhome.com/webservice';
    // Create new instance of SoapClient with the interhome web service URL
    $client = new
    SoapClient($this->config->item('interSoap'),array('trace'=>'1'));
    // Create new soap header and set username and password
    $header = new SoapHeader($ih_soap_ns,
            'ServiceAuthHeader',
    array('Username' => $ih_soap_user,'Password' =>
    $ih_soap_pass),
    true
    );
    // Prepare p// Prepare parameters


  $params = array('inputValue' =>array(
        'Page'=>$page,
        'PageSize'=>'10',
        'OrderDirection'=>'Ascending',//Descending
        'OrderBy'=>'Price',//Favorite,Place
        'LanguageCode'=>'EN',
        'CurrencyCode'=>'EUR',

        'CountryCode'=>trim($ajaxSearchCountryCode),
        'RegionCode'=>trim($ajaxSearchRegionCode),
        'PlaceCode'=>$ajaxSearchPlaceCode,
        'CheckIn'=> $ajaxSearchCheckinDate,
        'Duration'=>'7',
       'ThemeFilter'=>$ajaxSearchTheme,
       'HouseApartmentType'=>array('House'=>'House'),
       'SpecialOffer'=>'AnySpecialOffer',
         'PaxMin'=>'1',
         'PaxMax'=>'',
          'RoomsMin'=>'1',
         'RoomsMax'=>'',



    ) );



    try{
    $result = $client->__soapCall("Search",array('parameters'=> $params),null,$header);
```

Hi guys..Any Idea why this call when I pass any not empty array, as for example ,as I made for  'HouseApartmentType', returns  this error

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: 
>   Array to string conversion
>
> Filename:
>   controllers/houses.php
>
> Line
>   Number: 269

And when it's only empty array or a string the soap call function is working... I need to pass array of options to one parameter....

LINE 269 is

```
$result = $client->__soapCall("Search",array('parameters'=> $params),null,$header);
```

Comment: if your api only support strings, maybe you should serialize the array...

Comment: @Ibu it's not error I get from API server... I get this error during the call generation

Comment: The error said, array to string conversion so the error has something to do with the array being converted, can you show the line #269 of your code

Comment: I already edited the post and showed it @Ibu,it's a line where the call is made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you should look at the manual how a [soapcall work](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php):

```
$params = array(
     'Page'=>$page,
     'PageSize'=>'10',
     'OrderDirection'=>'Ascending',//Descending
     'OrderBy'=>'Price',//Favorite,Place
     'LanguageCode'=>'EN',
     'CurrencyCode'=>'EUR',
     'CountryCode'=>trim($ajaxSearchCountryCode),
     'RegionCode'=>trim($ajaxSearchRegionCode),
     'PlaceCode'=>$ajaxSearchPlaceCode,
     'CheckIn'=> $ajaxSearchCheckinDate,
     'Duration'=>'7',
     'ThemeFilter'=>$ajaxSearchTheme,
     'HouseApartmentType'=>'House', // changed to string instead of array
     'SpecialOffer'=>'AnySpecialOffer',
     'PaxMin'=>'1',
     'PaxMax'=>'', 
     'RoomsMin'=>'1', 
     'RoomsMax'=>'' );
```

i simplified the array and you should test it and look if this is the kind of result you are looking for.

Also look for ordering errors like the example shown in [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php#98348)

Comment: I know that with String it's working. I need to pass an array with 3! options House,Appartment and DetachedHouse, so that search will return more results.  :(((

Comment: i don't think it supports what you are trying to do, maybe you can pass the 3 options you want individually

Comment: just to know. how? maybe Nusoap?Any Idea, how could I make the same call with Nusoap? With Nusoap I have problem of passing header... I have put the Header part of code in original post...

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to add a new question for that, i am not familiar with Nusoap... sorry

Answer (score 3):

This is probably solved already, but I also had problems with this and I thought I should post here when I finally found the solution. (The solution is not nusoap, it throws the same error.)

The error only seems to come from the soapCall call generation, it really is the Web Service that causes it. When you run __soapCall, it first asks the server which datatypes the parameters should have and then tries to comply. So if you try to feed an array when the service expects a string, it will do the array to string conversion when the request is generated.